# How do I create a callback API in springboot framework?

Tags: api, spring-boot

The scenario goes something like this. I've a 3rd party system that accepts 'callback' endpoint and upon a specific event (at the 3rd party system), a new API request to my callback endpoint will be posted.

Couple of years back, I've created rest API with springboot - which exposes an endpoint that's callable and other 3rd party systems will call the API as and when needed.

Are they both same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question, yes, both are same. I've a bit better understanding of APIs and any publicly accessible endpoint can be used as callback endpoint.